# R shiny: Inserting math/latex symbols in input functions

Tags: r, shiny, latex, mathjax

I know there exist many tutorials teaching you how to use `withMatJax()` to insert math equations into your shiny app. However, I'm looking to insert math/latex symbols into the checkbox input label. For example, this is what I have:

```
checkboxGroupInput("inputmean", "Mean", choices = list_choices, selected = 0.01, inline = TRUE)
```

In the code snippet above, `list_chocies` is the list of choices that the user can click on, where `"Mean"` is the title of this checkbox group. However, I would like to do `"Mean \mu"`, where `\mu` will be translated by latex.

I don't just want to insert a greek symbol, since I will be adding more complicated symbols such as `\bar{\mu}`. I need latex to interpret. Is this possible?

Comment: As you said these are Latex symbols, However in shiny you will need HTML symbols. Check here for HTML symbols http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html

Comment: Just a comment, you could use KaTeX instead of MathJax. Is faster and the character are not computed by the client but by the server. It uses only fonts, CSS and javascript (the latter only server side if you want).

Comment: Try using `"Mean \\(\\mu\\)"` and seeing if that works.  The math delimiters `\(` and `\)` are needed by MathJax to identify the math on the page, and you have to double all backslashes when you use them in a javascript string literal.

Comment: Have a look at shinymath https://github.com/tomicapretto/shinymath